# How to use CSPs on iFrames

Tags: javascript, html, css, sandbox, content-security-policy

I am using an iFrame to contain an external html source `https://good.com/main.html`

```
<iframe src=“https://good.com/main.html" scrolling="no" style="overflow: hidden; height: 700px;"></iframe>
```

But `good.com/main.html` imports and executes the following javascript

```
https://good.com/a.js
https://good.com/b.js
https://bad.com/c.js
```

Is there a way to prevent `good.com/main.html` importing and executing `bad.com/c.js`? More specifically, prevent any resource that does not have the same domain as `https://good.com`?

I tried *sandboxing* the iFrame

```
<iframe sandbox=“allow-same-origin allow-scripts” src=“https://good.com/main.html” scrolling="no" style="overflow: hidden; height: 700px;"></iframe>
```

But it still imports and executes the `https://bad.com/c.js`

*Is there a way to prevent the source from importing and executing any external js?*

I read about [CSPs on iFrames](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-cspee/), but I am unsure of it’s usage.

Answer (score 5):

Broadly speaking, you can't.  Iframes have their own CSP and you can't pass a policy in from the parent page.

That said, the "csp" attribute of the iframe element, that you link to in the question, somewhat allows this.  It allows you to **request** that the iframe source apply the CSP that you set in the "csp" attribute; but you can't enforce it, merely ask. So you can theoretically do:

`<iframe csp="default-src 'none';" ...>`

The source of the iframe may or may not implement the CSP you request.

Note this is brand new and is (reportedly) only supported in Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Is there a way to build a wrapper over the existing iFrame and sandbox to achieve this?

Comment: I suppose you could use cUrl to fetch the content of the page, and output the content directly on your own page. Worth a try